# Why does JavaScript not load all pictures?

Tags: javascript, image, loading

I have this code snippet below...
You can see I am trying to load 9 pictures.
When I execute the following code, I only get an alert 7 times and the console does never log "all images loaded". Why is this?

```
    var images = [];
    edge_topleft = new Image(); images.push(edge_topleft);
    edge_topright = new Image(); images.push(edge_topright);
    edge_bottomleft = new Image(); images.push(edge_bottomleft);
    edge_bottomright = new Image(); images.push(edge_bottomright);
    edge_cross = new Image(); images.push(edge_cross);
    block = new Image(); images.push(block);
    ice = new Image(); images.push(ice);
    way_lr = new Image(); images.push(way_lr);
    way_ud = new Image(); images.push(way_ud);


    var len = images.length;
    var counter = 0;
    [].forEach.call(images, function( img ) {
        img.addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter, false);
    } );

    function incrementCounter() {
        counter++;
        alert(counter);
        if ( counter === len ) {
            console.log("all images loaded");
        }
    }

    edge_topleft.src = "https://dummyimage.com/10";
    edge_topright = "https://dummyimage.com/20";
    edge_bottomleft = "https://dummyimage.com/30";
    edge_bottomright.src = "https://dummyimage.com/40";
    edge_cross.src = "https://dummyimage.com/50";
    block.src = "https://dummyimage.com/60";
    ice.src = "https://dummyimage.com/70";
    way_lr.src = "https://dummyimage.com/80";
    way_ud.src = "https://dummyimage.com/90";
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnoaj8bg/

Anybody that knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because you're missing `.src` on two assignments.

Comment: @Siguza I am the most stupid person on the planet. I overlooked this for like 2 hours now! thank you for pointing it out.